# Recyclerview on item click row animation on wrong position

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with each row consisting of left icon and text. Onclicking the row , I trying to switch the image on the imageview using an animationDrawable. The animation works but clicking on the row starts the animation on a different position

```
 protected class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Bind(R.id.contact_name) protected TextView contactNameView;
    @Bind(R.id.contact_number) protected TextView contactNumberView;
    @Bind(R.id.add_contact_icon) protected ImageView addContactImageView;
    private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindContact(Contact contact) {
        setContactName(contact.getName());
        setContactNumberOrEmail(contact.getNumberOrEmail());
    }

    @Override public void onClick(View view) {

            animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) addContactImageView.getDrawable();
            animationDrawable.setColorFilter(primaryColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            if (animationDrawable.isRunning()) {
                animationDrawable.stop();
            }
            animationDrawable.start();
            Contact contact = (Contact) view.getTag();
            listener.onContactSelected(contact);

    }


}
```

Comment: Your not differentiating one click listener from another. Set a new OnClickListener in the method instead of making your class implement it.  that should solve your problem.

Comment: I have to add an item on row click which I am doing on listener.onContactSelected() and calling notifydatasetchanged. Doing so is causing the issue. If I remove the notifydatasetchanged call , it works